# When should a question be changed into a CW?

Tags: discussion, community-wiki

I [asked about non-D&D megadungeons](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/2394) and I was looking for either a "No" or a comprehensive answer. What I'm getting are single bits of what could be a comprehensive answer, spread across multiple answers.

At what point should a question be turned into a community wiki? Should these sorts of questions—ones that could have a comprehensive answer, but just aren't attracting one—be turned into a CW earlier, or should the asker and the community hold out for a comprehensive answer? Generally, should we be pro-active about converting to community wiki, or patient about it?

Comment: possible duplicate of [What does Community Wiki (CW) mean?](http://meta.rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/813/what-does-community-wiki-cw-mean)

Answer (score 1):

It's easier to turn a question into a community wiki than it is to change it back. (I'm not even sure you can change it back. I can't.) So patience seems in order. If people pick up some "extra" rep for providing part of a comprehensive answer, that's not so bad.

I think at this point if I were you I'd convert your megadungeon question, though. I could edit my answer to include all the individual answers, but that doesn't really improve the question as a whole. The information is there either way.

Comment: Wiki is indeed one way. You cannot change it back.

Comment: Although on meta.SO people are asking about [making that a little less strict](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/63908/accidental-community-wiki-entries).

Answer (score 0):

I think we should convert to community wiki when the question starts getting out of hand.

If you want a single comprehensive answer and instead start getting single answers, go ahead and convert!

Leaving it open does two things:

- People get rep for partial answers, which encourages them to keep giving them.
- Makes it harder to merge the answers into the one answer you really want.

Answer (score 0):

I could go either way on this. The question is properly asked; you couldn't have known that the value of the thread would be in the *list* of answers of relatively equal significance. Had you known, I would have started out by making it wiki.

If you felt that the question should have been community wiki from the start, the best thing to do is flag the question for moderator attention and request that it be converted by a moderator. You could, of course, convert it yourself but that would not convert the answers given before you made the conversion. A moderator making it wiki would convert *all* the answers in one shot.

Your choice.

Answer (score 0):

Anything that is a list without a "right" answer should be a community wiki from the get-go. This is obviously a list question, hence...

Comment: The general question stands though: When should a question be converted to CW in cases where it wasn't obvious from the get-go?

Comment: As soon as it's obvious?

Comment: However, it should have been obvious this was a list question, I would think...  Unless you actually wanted a yes or no answer.  But besides "no" the only possible response would have been to list ones right?  I am not sure a single person giving a comprehensive answer is a reasonable expectation given the scope of the RPG hobby, is what I'm saying.

Comment: Fair enough. I think I was unconsciously assuming the existence of a megadungeon enthusiast who would be familiar with them across systems, so there would either be a "no" or a "yes, and these are them." Which is to say: it may not be obvious to the asker, so we should have a policy for conversion after the fact. "When obvious" might be enough.